Estimating asymmetric shocks in local projections (lpirfs package in R)
I am trying to analyse the effects of asymmetric shocks using panel local projections. My shock variable is called SS2_FNET_E. To distinguish between positive and negative shocks, I created a dummy variable called switching that takes a value of 1 if the shock variable takes a positive value and 0 otherwise. This is the code I’m using. My question is: is this the correct way of analysing asymmetric shocks using a dummy variable and lp_nl_panel function?
There are very few examples on the Internet for using lp_nl_panel. Therefore, I could not be sure that I’m on the right track.
Thanks
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(COUNTRY) %>%
  mutate(switching=if_else(SS2_FNET_E > 0, 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

IRF_NL <- lp_nl_panel(data_set =  df2, 
                            endog_data = "lrealGDP",
                            cumul_mult = TRUE,
                            shock = "SS2_FNET_E",
                            diff_shock = F,
                            panel_model = "within",
                            panel_effect = "individual",
                            robust_cov        = "vcovSCC",
                            switching= "switching",
                            use_logistic =FALSE,
                            lag_switching = FALSE,
                            gamma=10,
                            l_fd_exog_data= c("SS2_FNET_E", "lrealGDP","policy_rate"), 
                            lags_fd_exog_data=4, 
                            confint = 1.65, 
                            hor = 12
)


No, you should estimate two separate equations: one where you include positive (and null) shocks, and another where you include only negative (and null) ones. Transforming your code accordingly, this becomes:
df2 <- df %>% 
       group_by(COUNTRY) %>%
       mutate(SS2_FNET_E_pos = if_else(SS2_FNET_E > 0, SS2_FNET_E, 0),
       SS2_FNET_E_neg = if_else(SS2_FNET_E < 0, SS2_FNET_E, 0)) %>%
       ungroup()

IRF_NL_neg <- lp_nl_panel(data_set =  df2, 
                        endog_data = "lrealGDP",
                        cumul_mult = TRUE,
                        shock = "SS2_FNET_E_neg",
                        diff_shock = F,
                        panel_model = "within",
                        panel_effect = "individual",
                        robust_cov        = "vcovSCC",
                        use_logistic =FALSE,
                        lag_switching = FALSE,
                        gamma=10,
                        l_fd_exog_data= c("SS2_FNET_E", "lrealGDP","policy_rate"), 
                        lags_fd_exog_data=4, 
                        confint = 1.65, 
                        hor = 12
           )


IRF_NL_pos <- lp_nl_panel(data_set =  df2, 
                        endog_data = "lrealGDP",
                        cumul_mult = TRUE,
                        shock = "SS2_FNET_E_pos",
                        diff_shock = F,
                        panel_model = "within",
                        panel_effect = "individual",
                        robust_cov        = "vcovSCC",
                        use_logistic =FALSE,
                        lag_switching = FALSE,
                        gamma=10,
                        l_fd_exog_data= c("SS2_FNET_E", "lrealGDP","policy_rate"), 
                        lags_fd_exog_data=4, 
                        confint = 1.65, 
                        hor = 12
      )

Note that I haven't adjusted/corrected anything else in the code.
More generally, there are more intricate and complete ways of testing for sign/size non-linearities. See this working paper for a different approach. In practice you add a second term that is a non-linear transformation of the shock. They provide suggestions on the kind of transformations to use.
